# how to connect between two virtual machines in different computers via TCP

Tags: networking, tcp

I am trying to connect two different virtual machines together, with each on a different computer. I tried using NAT and port forwarding that is, when the client tries to connect on another computer using that computer's IP address, the computer "transfers" the connection to the virtual machine(containing the server) on the particular port sent by the client.The server listens on that port. But that doesn't seem to happen. What happens is that the client tries to connect for a while, then, it outputs "connection failed". Is there a way I connect them with another method or am I doing something wrong with this method? By the way, I've tried checking online(and here) to do this but to no avail. Also, the two computers have the same IP address. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using "bridged" mode network adapters on your virtual machines (as opposed to NAT).

Bridged mode creates a virtual switch connection that makes each VM appear to be just another machine on the network, so you can access them without any special handling/knowledge of the VM.

Comment: Do I use the IP address of the host to communicate with the VM?

Comment: No, in bridged mode each VM will get its own IP as if it were a real device plugged directly into your network.